# SVG : How to convert meters to points ratio

Tags: svg

I have a building floor map in SVG whith these size attributes:

```
width="594.75pt" height="841.5pt"
```

The size of the map, is in meters : 40x52.

What is the correct way to convert meters to points ?

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(pathToSvg);
while (reader.Read() && string.IsNullOrEmpty(width) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(height))
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            if (reader.Name == @"svg")
            {
                width = reader.GetAttribute(@"width");
                height = reader.GetAttribute(@"height");
            }
            break;
    }
}

// Remove pt from width and height strings
width = width.Replace("pt", string.Empty); 
height = height.Replace("pt", string.Empty);

// Convert to double values
double widthInPoint = double.Parse(width, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double heightInPoint = double.Parse(height, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// compute the ratio meters/points in both dimensions <=== Is this section right ??
// 594.75pt => 40 meters
// 1pt => X meters

double ratioX = mapHorizontalMeterSize / widthInPoint;
double ratioY = mapVerticalMeterSize / heightInPoint;

// Compute the Beacon position in points
double radiusInPoint = Math.Round(radius / ratioX, 2);
double beaconXPositionOnMapInPt = Math.Round((customMapX / ratioX) - (radius / ratioX), 2);
double yPos = Math.Round((customMapY / ratioY) - (radius / ratioY), 2);

// SVG positioning is top left corner by default, we are bottom left (originCornerId  == 0)
double beaconYPositionOnMapInPt = originCornerId == 0 ? heightInPoint - yPos : yPos;

string tmpPath;
var reaaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
reaaderSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
using (var svgReader = XmlReader.Create(path, reaaderSettings))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(svgReader);

    var xmlns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
    var xlinkns = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xlink");

    // Add the circle
    doc.Root.Add(new XElement(xmlns + "circle",
        new XAttribute("stroke", "blue"),
        new XAttribute("stroke-width", "3"),
        new XAttribute("cx", $"{beaconXPositionOnMapInPt.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}pt"),
        new XAttribute("cy", $"{beaconYPositionOnMapInPt.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}pt"),
        new XAttribute("r", $"{radiusInPoint.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}"),
        new XAttribute("fill-opacity", "0.1")
        ));

    // Add the beacon image
    //XNamespace xlinkns = "https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    doc.Root.Add(new XElement(xmlns + "image",
        new XAttribute("x", $"{beaconXPositionOnMapInPt.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}pt"),
        new XAttribute("y", $"{yPos.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}pt"),
        new XAttribute(xlinkns + "href", $"data:image/{iconFormat};base64,{icon}")
        ));

    tmpPath = FileHelpers.NextAvailableFilename(path);

    doc.Save(tmpPath);
}
```

The result is absolutely not what I'm expecting.
The svg file is almost 3Mb in size and I can't show it here.

Comment: Why is there a need to convert from meter to pt? if you define your `viewBox` accordingly, your inner units are more or less independent from the SVG external size.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units

Comment: @Sirko I need to programmatically introduce a circle at a specific position whose unit is meters

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add new elements with dimensions specified in meters you could use a conversion helper function to find the right **scaling multiplier/divisor**

If your svg's dimensions are 594.8 × 841.5 user units
594.8 × 841.5 pt (real life print format - A4)
containing a map that is 40×52m in real life:

Meter to point multiplier: 2834.64388 (for converting meters to points/user units)
Scaling divisor: 40*2834.64388 / 594.8

#### Js example

I'm adding a rectangle at x/y=20m; width/height=10m; using my helper function
`m2UserUnits('20m', scaleDivisor)` that will convert meter to user units.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let realWidth = '40m';
let userWidth = '594.8pt';
let m2PtMultiplier = 2834.64388;
let scaleDivisor = parseFloat(realWidth)*m2PtMultiplier / parseFloat(userWidth);

//append to svg
let ns ='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let rect = document.createElementNS(ns, 'rect');
rect.setAttribute('x', m2UserUnits('20m', scaleDivisor) );
rect.setAttribute('y', m2UserUnits('20m', scaleDivisor) );
rect.setAttribute('width', m2UserUnits('10m', scaleDivisor) );
rect.setAttribute('height', m2UserUnits('10m', scaleDivisor) );
svg.appendChild(rect)


let circle = document.createElementNS(ns, 'circle');
circle.setAttribute('cx', m2UserUnits('5m', scaleDivisor) );
circle.setAttribute('cy', m2UserUnits('5m', scaleDivisor) );
circle.setAttribute('r', m2UserUnits('5m', scaleDivisor) );
svg.appendChild(circle)


//unit conversion
function m2UserUnits(val, scaleDivisor){
    let valNum = parseFloat(val);
    if(val.indexOf('m')!==-1){
        valNum *= 2834.64388;
    }
    return valNum/scaleDivisor;
}
```

```css
svg{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width:40%;
}

text{
font-size:32px
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 594.8 841.5" >
        <rect id="bg-A4" fill="#FFFFFF" width="594.8" height="841.5"/>
        <rect id="map-40x52m" fill="#EEEEEE" width="594.8" height="773.2"/>
        <text x="50%" y="90%" text-anchor="middle">Map area: 40&times;52m (real life)</text>
        <text x="50%" y="98%" text-anchor="middle">svg viewport: 594.8 &times; 841.5 user units</text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: My code is correct, I just had to [remove the 'pt' suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73104848/15186) from the coordinates.